# how to consume kafka topics in sequence in Micronaut

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-topic, micronaut-kafka

topic 1 and topic 2 i want to be able to consume topic 1 and only after consuming the message start consuming topic 2 message.

I tried to sendTo the data from topic1 to topic2 and setting autoStartUp() property to false for topic2 but how do i hold topic2 from not consuming simultaneously

I see a way to do this in sprinboot using ContainerGroupSequencer but not sure what is the way to do in Micronaut